# Does dictionaries add another one in a random order?

Tags: python, dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ6eK.jpg)

Please find the above program that I have used as an example to demonstrate what happened when I tried to update one dictionary with another.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in dictionary data type does not maintain order. If you require order for your dictionary, you can try using ordered dictionaries:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict